# Grouping / Multiple grouping with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I'm trying to output some data, grouped, then group it again.

Here's some example data (from db)

[image: example data]

I'm trying to output this, grouped like so:

```
Best Type Name
 - Discipline name
   -- Result  
   -- Result
   -- Result
```

CompetitorBest class looks like:

```
public class CompetitorBest
{
    public int ResultId { get; set; }
    public string BestTypeName { get; set; }
    public int BestTypeOrder { get; set; }
    public string DisciplineName { get; set; }
    public string ResultValue { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResultDate { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, I've got the following

```
var bestsGroups = from b in Model.CompetitorBests
                  group b by new { b.BestTypeName, b.BestTypeOrder }
                  into grp
                  orderby grp.Key.BestTypeOrder
                  select new
                  {
                      BestType = grp.Key.BestTypeName,
                      Results = grp.ToList()
                  };
```

But this obviously doesn't take into account the grouping by DisciplineName.
My output code is something like:

```
foreach (var bestsGroup in bestsGroups)
{
    <h2>@bestsGroup.BestType</h2>

    foreach (var result in bestsGroup.Results)
    {
        //i am guessing here i'll need another foreach on the discipline group....
        <p>@result.DisciplineName</p>
        <p>@result.ResultId </p>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
from b in Model.CompetitorBests
group b by new { b.BestTypeName, b.BestTypeOrder } into grp
orderby grp.Key.BestTypeOrder
select new
{
    BestType = grp.Key.BestTypeName,
    Results = from d in grp
              group d by d.DisciplineName into grp2
              select new
              {
                  DisciplineName = grp2.Key,
                  Results = grp2
              }
};
```

**Edit:**

Iterate over it like this:

```
foreach (var bestsGroup in bestsGroups)
{
    <h2>@bestsGroup.BestType</h2>

    foreach (var discipline in bestsGroup.Results)
    {
        <p>@discipline.DisciplineName</p>

        foreach (var result in discipline.Results)
        {
            <p>@result.ResultId</p>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the foreach i'd use to iterate over it?

Comment: @alexjamesbrown I added an example to the answer.